# Изменить текст QTextEdit при клике по нему в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Пишу калькулятор на С++ в Qt Creator. Хочу сделать так, чтобы при клике по текстовому полю (когда там уже введен текст) старый текст убирался и ставился новый. Не пойму, как переопределить mousePressEvent так, чтобы он срабатывал именно на клик по полю, а не где угодно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможную реализацию. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Если на основе `Q..Edit` то пишешь свой класс:

```
class MyEdit : public QLineEdit{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyEdit(QWidget *parent = 0): QLineEdit(parent){};
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override
    {
        setText("твой текст");
    }
};
```